# Twilio serverless functions - recording an inbound call

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio serverless functions to handle inbound calls. I have multiple functions that handle the execution of the call. I want record the entire call. When I initiate call recording in the function using the recording API, the recording is stareted. However, as soon as the function execution redirects to another function, the recording API execution is terminated (due to the async handling withing twilio, all background processes are terminated). What is the best mechanism within twilio serverless functions to record an entire inbound call.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to let Twilio handle the recording for you and to receive it at a callback URL via [`recordingStatusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) (which could also run on Serverless):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" recordingStatusCallback="/recordings"
 />
</Response>
```

Comment: Hi there, it appears the record verb will only record the caller's input. I am trying to record the entire call (both channels). I was looking at the documentation and using the recordings API in my serverless function . I am adding this function call before I add my other verbs and actions:  
client.calls(event.CallSid)
      .recordings
      .create()
      .then(recording => console.log(recording.sid));

Comment: However, I am certainly missing something.